# How to add custom ObjectId to parse-server object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a problem when adding data to my `User` class by Mongoose that can't update it later by parse API.

I've found that's because of mongoose use `ObjectId` for `_id` field and parse just work with plain string as `ObjectId`.

The question is how can I set my custom unique plain string as ObjectId in `Parse Server` object creation?

Comment: Please provide some concrete code of what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to save more data to a `Parse.User`?

Comment: I'm trying to add data to Parse.User with mongoose client. but generated objectId with mongoose is not compatible with parse spec(only plain string) so I cant update new object later with parse

Comment: I found this(https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/6177) PR but not documented anywhere

Comment: This PR that you sent is useful only if you try to load data using the API. Since you are using mongoose, you will have to create the ids in the same format that Parse creates. You can see how Parse does that [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/cryptoUtils.js#L37). You should generate in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```js
const cryptoUtils = require('parse-server/lib/cryptoUtils');
const id = cryptoUtils.newObjectId();
```

Source: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/cryptoUtils.js